# When writing SBT tasks in build.sbt, how do I use my library dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt

How do I add an SBT task to build.sbt that uses an external dependency?

e.g. I would like to write a task that utilises the AWS SDK client

```
libraryDependencies += "aws-sdk-name" % "etc. "%etc"

uploadTask := {
   val s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(...);
   s3Client.putObject(...)
}
```

However, there will understandably be compile errors because the dependency won't will be generated by sbt!

The docs for tasks are restricted to very simple use cases i.e. println(...).

A plugin seems a bit overkill to me for this so I am hoping there is another way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`sbt` is [a *recursive* build system](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Organizing-Build.html#sbt+is+recursive), so just place the library dependency you need in your build into your `project` folder:

```
your-project/
    project/
        build-dependencies.sbt
    src/
        main/ # etc.
    build.sbt
```

#### build-dependencies.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "aws-sdk-name" % "etc. "%etc"
```

#### build.sbt

```
// Or in project/SomeBuildFile.scala
uploadTask := {
  val s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(...);
  s3Client.putObject(...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

Relevant docs: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Organizing-Build.html#sbt+is+recursive